# Relation: Translating a node removes its relation

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, entities

I have a weird problem regarding the Relation module and translations in Drupal 7. I have types for companies and buildings and I have a relation between company and building that means that the company is situated in the building.

If I have a company A in the default language Swedish and translate it to English the new translated node will work fine, but old node in Swedish will kind of lose its company-building relation (it is still visible in admin, but I can't see it in my views and it has disappeared from the field_data_endpoints table. If I do some changes to the Swedish version and save it, the relation will become visible again, but the English translation will lose it instead.

Any ideas about what might be causing it, or how I should go about finding that out?

Comment: Is it Drupal 6, 7, 8 ? What kind of relations are you using ?

Comment: Thanks for helping me clarify my problem statement. I have updated the question.